# Why Python and pip can't be found neither on cmd or in IDE?

Tags: python, pip, pygame, python-import

I messed up with the files and deleted some 32bit Python files because I thought that they're unnecessary.

Then I discover that they had some interesting files to run some specific modules so I just uninstalled Python and re-downloaded it. When I tried to run pip in cmd and even git bash it shows that Python is not defined even after I added it to path same with pip module, now no code can be executed.

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.dis`play.set_mode((800, 500))
```

What shall I do to fix it?

Comment: if you've added it to path, you need to restart cmd for it to work.  If that doesn't work, uninstall python and reinstall and in the very beginning of the install make sure the checkbox for 'add python to path' is checked.

Answer (score 0):

As you not provide the message, that appears when python or pip is not found, all below is just my speculations about the common mistakes in more or less close cases (as I undertand that).

Programs may be not found as they are not in your %PATH%. To ensure that you need to open new CMD window and issue

```
echo %PATH%
```

If there is no signs of folder your Python was installed in the output you'll see - that's the case I'm talking about. Otherwise just ignore all the following part of my answer.

In that case one of the easiest way is to properly uninstall Python and then install it once again. Don't forget [to mark "Add to PATH" option during install](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#installation-steps).